# Fill a portion of drawn image in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fill

i drew an image using drawImage() api of html5 canvas. now i want to fill the white spaces of that drew image with different colors (individual box individual color). how can i do it? i am using html5 canvas and jquery.

i want to fill the white spaces with different color and those white spaces are not proper rectangular box.

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of the code you used and give a visual clue of what you are after?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/azDNh/
here i want to fill the white spaces with different color and those white spaces are not proper rectangular box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[ changed answer after clarification from questioner ]**

Given: an image that has many fully-enclosed transparent areas.

This is a method to fill each transparent area with a different color:

1. Use context.getImageData to get an array of each canvas pixels [r,g,b,a] value.
2. Loop thru the array and find the first transparent pixel (the "a" value ==0)
3. Floodfill the entire transparent area containing that pixel with a new opaque color (replace the r,g,b values with your new color and replace the "a" value ==255).
4. Repeat step#2 until all the transparent areas have been filled with new unique colors.

**To get you started...**

William Malone wrote a ***very nice*** article on how to get and use canvas's [r,g,b,a] color array.

His article also shows you how to "floodfill" -- replace an existing color with a new color in an entire contiguous area.

In your case, you would replace transparent pixels with a new color.

This is his article:

http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/

**[Addition to question: insert images into areas ]**

You need to make each colorized area transparent again—**one at a time**

If you save each area's starting pixel from when you originally colorized the areas, you can start with that pixel and re-floodfill an area.  This time you’ll set the alpha component of each pixel in that area to 0 (transparent).

As each single area is transparent you use compositing to *draw the new image only where the existing pixels are transparent*. The composite you want is context.globalCompositeOperation=”source-out”.

These examples show:

- After uniquely colorizing each area.
- After making 1 area transparent (the top-right area is transparent).
- After compositing an image into the transparent area.

[image][image][image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/azDNh/
here i want to fill the white spaces with different color and those white spaces are not proper rectangular box.

Comment: Your question is much cleared with this info.  See my revised answer.

Comment: thanks markE for very clear answer. now i want to take it to the next level. how can i draw an image into that white block and not overflow to the neighbour blocks. i go through the link you mentioned. how can i change it to use for image instead of color fill.

Comment: You need to make each colorized area transparent again—**one at a time** (since each area is now uniquely colored, you can floodfill a unique color with transparency—alpha=0).  When one single area is transparent you can use compositing to draw the new image only where the existing pixels are transparent. The composite you want is context.globalCompositeOperation=”source-out”.

Comment: thanks a lot markE. thanks for your time. you explained everything i asked in a crystal clear way...........

Answer (score 0):

//draw some white, green, and blue stripes

```
    for (var i = 0; i < canvas.width; i += 10) {
        for (var j = 0; j < canvas.height; j += 10) {
            context.fillStyle = (i % 20 === 0) ? "#fff" : ((i % 30 === 0) ? "#0f0" : "#00f");
            context.fillRect(i, j, 10, 10);
        }
    }
    var imagedata = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
            pixels = imagedata.data;


       //if found white pixel i.e 255,255,255 changes it to 0,102,204
```

//you can change it to another color as u wish

```
    for (var offset = 0, len = pixels.length; offset < len; offset += 4) {

        if(pixels[offset]==255 &&
                pixels[offset+1]==255 &&
                pixels[offset+2]==255)

        {pixels[offset] = 0; //
        pixels[offset + 1] = 102; //
        pixels[offset + 2] = 204; //
        }

    }
    context.putImageData(imagedata, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Here is what ABDULMOIZ based his code on, if anyone is interested: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp